# Is there a way to run genymotion in hidpi mode?

Tags: macos, retina, genymotion

I am trying to run genymotion on a rMBP in HiDPI mode. Apparently my Virtualbox version already has `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key> <true/>` set in Contents/Info.plist

Still genymotion does scale the vm up to 200%, which not only makes everything look pretty blurry, but also adds blurriness from downscaling.

I am using Virtualbox 4.3.2 and genymotion 1.3.1 on OSX 10.9.

Comment: same problem today on the most recent versions of mentioned software. (facepalm.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported at the moment (Genymotion 2.2.2).

[From Genymotion's twitter:](https://twitter.com/soffes/status/454151138690867200)

> Sam Soffes @Genymotion any plans for Retina Mac support?
>
> Genymotion @soffes absolutely, but it will takes time, as we need to
>   change a lots of things to support HiDef screens.

---

**Update:** Genymotion now fully supports Retina screen resolutions [[Version 2.7.0]](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/genymotion-2-7-0-retina-support-faster-adb/).

Answer (score 3):

Genymotion uses VirtualBox under the hood, and they probably will never support proper HiDPI rendering, because of flawed reasoning (like "other OSes don't know about HiDPI, so picture must be scaled").
[Source — comment to the ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10860#comment:23)

Although I'm not sure if the VirtualBox is actually used for *rendering* the picture… if not, then VirtualBox rendering problems are probably not an issue.